# How do you toggle/disable annotation helper links in Eclipse/TestNG?

Tags: eclipse, annotations, testng, toggle, disable

I recently updated Eclipse and its TestNG plugins (see attached images),
now I have these "helper" links hovering around my annotations and class declarations.  
While I can see how some may find this feature useful, for me, it is just annoying.

Where can I find the option(s) to turn these UI shortcut links off?

---

[image: Annoying Annotation Helpers]

---

---

[image: Eclipse IDE for Java Developers 2020-06 (4.16.0)]

---

---

[image: TestNG Eclipse Plugins]

---

---

[image]

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are so-called ***Code Minings*** can be enabled/disabled in *Window > **Preferences: Java > Editor > Code Minings***.